# Papers on tree based and linear models

Tags: algorithms

I am looking for papers which could give a greater understanding on differences between Tree based and linear based models.

Anybody can gove me some pointers?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest chapters „3 Linear Regression“ and „8 Tree-Based Methods“ in [An introduction to statistical learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf)